# NSImage drawInRect and TemplateImages

Tags: cocoa, drawrect, nsimage, appkit

In have an `NSImage` is a template image (that is, `[NSImage isTemplate]` returns `YES`).

When I use it inside an NSImageView, it is drawn correctly as a template image.

However, if I draw it manually using `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:`, it is drawn as a flat black image.

How can I draw an NSImage manually, and still get the 'template' effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special drawing of template images is part of CoreUI and not public.
You can imitate the effect with Quartz though. Details and code can be found in this answer here on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138497/100848